# V8 "Hello World" Example - Compiling on Ubuntu 13.10 - tons of undefined reference errors "icu_46"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, v8

I am trying to follow the basic "hello world" example for Google's V8 as found [here](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started).  I'm on Ubuntu 13.10, gcc version 4.8.1; this should be straighforward, no?

After building v8 itself and creating the hello world .cpp file, 
I run (exactly** as Google suggests)

** *Update:  Okay, per my comments on the accepted answer below, I unwittingly wasn't running it exactly as Google suggests, because I thought the braces in the file name were an instruction to the reader to choose one option, not a 
[syntax that g++ would understand](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).  Nontheless, it still doesn't work except with the additions suggested in the answer below*

```
   g++ -Iinclude helloworld.cpp -o hello_world out/x64.debug/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.x64.a -lpthread
```

And get bombarded with compile errors.  There are too many to print here, but nearly all the errors are of the form:

```
   undefined reference to 'icu_46 ...'
```

for example (some sample lines)

```
   /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/i18n.cc:138: undefined reference to `icu_46::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
   /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/i18n.cc:125: undefined reference to `icu_46::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
   /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/i18n.cc:147: undefined reference to `icu_46::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
```

After much Googling I can figure out this has something to do with something called ICU (see http://userguide.icu-project.org/howtouseicu) but why I'm getting the error, and what I can do about it, I don't know.

While the majority of errors are icu_46 related, there are some like this as well, from the 'bootstrapper.o':

```
     /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/x64.debug/obj.target/v8_base.x64/src/bootstrapper.o: In function `v8::internal::Bootstrapper::NativesSourceLookup(int)':
     /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/bootstrapper.cc:77: undefined reference to `v8::internal::NativesCollection<(v8::internal::NativeType)0>::GetBuiltinsCount()'
     /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/bootstrapper.cc:81: undefined reference to `v8::internal::NativesCollection<(v8::internal::NativeType)0>::GetRawScriptSource(int)'
     /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/x64.debug/obj.target/v8_base.x64/src/bootstrapper.o: In function `v8::internal::Genesis::CompileBuiltin(v8::internal::Isolate*, int)':
     /home/ray/Playground/v8/out/../src/bootstrapper.cc:1448: undefined reference to `v8::internal::NativesCollection<(v8::internal::NativeType)0>::GetScriptName(int)'
```

I'm Googled endlessly on this and have found signs that other people have run into the issue but no solutions.  Any help will be hugely appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Haven't tried myself, but maybe add `\`pkg-config --libs --cflags icu-uc icu-io\`` to the compilation line (including the back-ticks).  Also run `apt-get install -y libicu-dev` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that seems promising but actually (and oddly) doesn't change the outcome at all.

Comment: Did you run `make dependencies`?

Comment: @Andreas:  yes, and just did it again for good measure.  Makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.6.3 and v8 3.22.18.
To compile hello_world.cc successfully it is necessary to add icu .a libraries and link to rt library too. As you have built v8 with make x64.debug your completed command should be:

```
g++ -Wall -Iinclude -o hello_world hello_world.cc ./out/x64.debug/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_{base.x64,snapshot}.a ./out/x64.debug/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicu{i18n,uc,data}.a -lrt
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked (Except I also had to add -lpthread to the end of the command) thank you.  For future reference, can you help me understand "how" you figured that out, and what steps someone could take other than posting to SO? :-)  Specifically I'm wondering whether Google's instructions (in my original question) are just wrong, or whether there is some subtlety about versions etc. etc.

Comment: It works for me without `-lpthread`. As I'm not C/C++ developer first of all I figured out how to work with .so and .a files on compilation and that order of .a files makes sense. Than I tried different combination and carefully read logs (undefined reference to icu_46/undefined reference to rt) to find this solution. So it is a combination of fortune and trials and errors (and lack of solution in google :)

Comment: That's funny, it works for me without the `-lrt` but NOT without the `-lpthread`; oh, the vagueries of these things.  But I also realize that another mistake I was making was assuming that the braces in the filename were the Documentation's way of saying "choose one" - I did not realize that g++ would understand the braces and include all the files.  Maybe I'll need to ask another question about that feature, which I can't find documented anywhere...

Comment: I did the same mistake as you (about braces).

Comment: For future reference:  Brace Expansion, I guess it's a BASH feature http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion